# Model field dependent on same model foreign key object

Tags: django

Title seems complicated but its not really.

Lets say I have 2 models:

First is Choices that contains a title and boolean to see if the choice is correct or not.

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Second is Check that checks if the use has chosen the correct choice:

```
class CheckQuestion(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    selected_choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=None)
```

The correct field must be equal to the correct field of the selected choice. So basically:

```
correct = selected_choice.correct
```

I have tried implementing these using @property like this:

```
@property
    def correct(self):
        if self.selected_choice.correct:
            correct = True
        else:
            correct = False
        return correct
```

And I tried save like this:

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.correct = self.selected_choice.correct
        super(CheckQuestion,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

But neither worked, property method was giving giving a "cannot be null" error and save method just always returned false.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have set your default value on your BooleanField to `None` but you don't allow for null values. You should set this to `False` to make the main Choice model pattern. This would explain the method error.

```py
correct = models.BooleanField(default=None) # change to False
```

Secondly, your model method can be made simpler - no if-statement needed.

```py
@property
    def correct(self):
        return self.selected_choice.correct
```

As to why the `save()` override option always returns False, it would seem that the Choice object must have a False correct field. I would suggest triple checking whether that is the case or not - the `save()` code looks okay to me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changing the default to false didn't fix the property method. I kept getting this error `null value in column "correct" of relation "app_checkquestion" violates not-null constraint
`

However triple checked the save method and got it to work now. Thanks a lot!